# How would I resolve this snippet of PHP to allow receiving/outputting data from MySQL via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I'm not having an issue with storing the data via PDO(",,,") but am getting an error to receive/output the data using the following snippet.

```
public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
        ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $list = array();

    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
        $article = new Article( $row );
        $list[] = $article;
    }

    // Now get the total number of articles that matched the criteria
    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ));
}
```

I'm recieving the following error when using `mysql_escape_string()` -

> Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead. in C:\document.php on line 41

When I change it to `mysql_real_escape_string()` I receive the following errors -

> Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\document.php on line 41
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\document.php on line 41
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in C:\document.php on line 41

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using PDO, so don't use anything that's part of the antiquated `mysql_query` library, and that includes `mysql_real_escape_string`.

You can't just inject arbitrary `ORDER BY` criteria, you'll have to be really careful here. If it's a column you're sorting on, run it through a white-list of known-good columns and insert that text *only*. You don't want people supplying their own arbitrary columns to sort on, especially if they're not in the database.

Remember, escaping column names uses a totally different method than escaping MySQL data strings.

Comment: So how exactly do I change this snippet to work right? It would be very helpful because this had worked for me before and now it's just broken.

Comment: I'm not sure how it worked before. That would only support ordering by an arbitrary string, not a column. It might *appear* to work, but it'd really be sorting all rows by the same value, totally wrong. Try `$order` without escaping, but be **absolutely sure** this is not a user supplied parameter. You want `ORDER BY publicationDate DESC` not `ORDER BY 'publicationDate DESC'`.